# Inner Classes/Interfaces

Tags: apex, class, architecture, interface, inner-class

the guide says that one difference between Java and Apex is:

```
Inner classes and interfaces can only be declared one level deep inside an outer class.
```

Considering I know in Java what is an Inner class, an Interface and an Anonymous class, could you bring an example so to understand what "**one level deep inside**" means?
My guess is that could be something regarding OOP and the structure of inherithance a class or is considering the level deep as a nested structure, so that an inner classes

EDIT: there is an idea of Lambdas, please feel free to vote  at this official [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dk5sAAC), if you are beginner, see how lambdas make the code more readable the code with this simple [example](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that an inner class can't have an inner class in Apex. So a structure like this is legal and common, especially when implementing patterns like wrapper classes or dependency injection:

```
public with sharing class OuterClass {
    private class InnerClass {
        // Members here.
    }

    // Members here
}
```

However, this structure is not legal Apex:

```
public with sharing class OuterClass {
    private class InnerClass {
        private class InnerInnerClass {
            // Members here.
        }

        // Members here.
    }

    // Members here
}
```

With the same prohibition applying for inner interfaces as inner classes.

Note that this stricture is written in terms of **inner declaration**. It's about the class nesting hierarchy, not the inheritance tree.

Comment: accepted answer,  so I am afraid also anonymous inner classes and lambda expressions are not supported because of the nesting hierarchy of the class. This makes the code more difficult to read, but I guess the reasons are in the efficiency that wants to be obtained at runtime, because nested classes are going to be more expensive I reckon, and overall salesforce wants to maintain the code easier as possible because of the cloud structure. Could be correct?

Comment: You are correct. Apex supports neither anonymous classes nor lambda expressions (nor closures, nor function application).

Comment: you got my upvote as well

Comment: @trocchietto Like most features, it's really just a question of prioritization.  There's an [idea for lambdas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dk5sAAC) if you want to upvote it.  You could also check for existing ideas for other features and suggest them if they aren't posted already.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Lambdas are really important to me, added EDIT on my post so to inform in the future